# Change the working directory of a running process with C#

Tags: c#, cmd, process

I do not know if this is even possible without breaking/crashing the process but is there a way to change the working directory of a System.Diagnostics.Process like you would when executing the cd (change directory) command from the cmd.exe command line interface?

Comment: [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: This is only working for the C# process itself but is not callable on an external System.Diagnostics.Process or at least I do not know where to find it.

Comment: You should keep in mind that the working directory is not fixed and can change at any time by any operation.

Comment: I did hope so, but how can my c# application change the working directory of an external process?

Comment: AFAIK you can't change it for an already runnng process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per MSDN, there is only one function which can change current folder, `SetCurrentDirectory` and it has single string parameter,  so the change is for current process only.

```
            String oldWorkingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(myDirInfo.FullName);
            operation();
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(oldWorkingDir);
```

[ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 9):

You may set the working directory of the process with

```
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "dir".
```

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx).